# ASP.Net Identity 2 Using a custom data access layer like Enterprise Library

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am new to asp.net identity (ver. 2) and am about to start implementing it one of our MVC projects using the Claims based authorization mechanism instead of role based. I having been going through [this link](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) where what I understand from what is written is that I need to inherit Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager and create a CustomUserManager class and override its methods and then implement Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IUserStore to be consumed by my CustomUserManager class at the very least. There are other interfaces that I think were designed to be implemented for certain specific conditions like in my case the IUserClaimStore since I want to go with Claims based authorization. The reason mentioned is that I can change the store at a later date incase I want to change my persistence mechanism.

My questions are:

1. Since I am never going to change the persistence mechanism, is it really required that I implement all those classes and interfaces?
2. Going through the sample code the most important methods seem to be the following two code blocks:

**Identity Creation and save to session (code in DoLogin Method)**

```
// over simplified user object creation    
UserPoco userObject= MyDAL.GetUserDatabyLoginDetails(username,password); 

//identity created
var identity = CustomImplementationOfCreateIdentity(userObject, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

//saved to session
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

**CheckAccess**

```
   public class AppClaimsAuthManager: ClaimsAuthorizationManager
    {

        public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            var resource = context.Resource.First().Value;
            var action = context.Action.First().Value;

            //bool retVal = context.Principal.HasClaim("MyAction", "SampleResource");
            bool retVal = context.Principal.HasClaim(action, resource);
            bool baseRetVal= base.CheckAccess(context);

            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

**which is then used in controller methods like so**

```
 [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Operation = "delete", Resource = "SomeResource")]
        public ActionResult ClaimsBasedActionMethod()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Does it really matter how my user object is created via the CustomManager and CustomUserstore class implementations? Once the user name and password is verified and claims fetched from DB and my `userObject` created, I should be good to go right? I want this data to be fetched my service layer using enterprise library which I don't want to clog up with all identity framework related references.

Thoughts?